# WPF TwoWay not working on X (exit) but works on TAB or clicking elsewhere

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, two-way-binding

I have the following in my XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="TitleValue" 
         Text="{Binding ElementName=ListValue, Path=SelectedItem.Title, Mode=TwoWay}"

<TextBox Name="DescValue"
         Text="{Binding ElementName=ListValue, 
                        Path=SelectedItem.Description, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

When I enter a value in either TitleValue or DescValue and Tab or click on a different location in the window, the collection class properties are updated correctly.  Then when I click the X to exit the window, the data in the collection class is saved correctly.

However, when I enter a value in either of those fields, then click X to exit the window, the data in the collection class is saved, but the value entered is not saved for that particular field I was editing when I clicked X.

I implemented a lose focus event on the fields and they work, even when the X is clicked.  In those events I put the code:

```
private void Event_DescValue_LoseFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Import)ListValue.SelectedItem).Description = ((TextBox)e.OriginalSource).Text;
}
```

But that didn't work either.  the following does not work either:

```
Imports[ListValue.SelectedIndex].Description = ((TextBox)e.OriginalSource).Text;
```

How do I get the collection class Imports to update the selected class Import when X is clicked when in a field being edited?

It should work exactly like I had Tabbed off the field being edited or clicking elsewhere in the window.

Comment: Define "data in collection class is saved".  Where are you saving that data?

Comment: Try adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your binding's [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) to PropertyChanged.

Like so:

```
<TextBox Name="TitleValue" Text="{Binding ElementName=ListValue, 
     Path=SelectedItem.Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  But why is it not needed if you simply tab out of the edited field or click elsewhere on the window, but it is needed if after editing the field you click the X to exit the window?  This just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @RFM Sorry I took so long to respond...take a look at the MSDN documentation.  The default value for UpdateSourceTrigger is LostFocus on the Text property, however most other properties have a default UpdateSourceTrigger of PropertyChanged. 
[msdn]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx